# How to customise ASP.NET Core Grpc.Core.RpcException for correct Sentry issue tracking

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, sentry

We are using Sentry to monitor errors/issues on the ASP.NET Core gRPC service.

The issue is that the server returns `Grpc.Core.RpcException` for ALL exceptions, just with different messages and traces. As a result in Sentry, we have just one issue with hundreds of different error.

In other words - we want to split this somehow.

Comment: It sounds like a limitation Sentry should address in the OOTB experience. That said I imagine someone can write a work around here as an answer (e.g: using BeforeSend to mutate the event, for example

Comment: Best creating a ticket on the repository: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/new/